# Click on mobile element after search gets complete in appium

Tags: android, listview, automation, appium

I have created a script for searching an element and once it is visible I click on it.Below is the code of the same.

**Method call**

```
String xpath = //android.widget.TextView[@text='Some text to wait for'];
WebElement element = searchElement(user.getBroadCastName(), ByXPath.xpath(xpath));
                        if (element != null) {
                            element.click();
        }
```

**Method return element which matched the requirement**

```
 private WebElement searchElement(String stringToSearch, By findViewById) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Searching element from list " +findViewById);
            WebElement searchBar = appiumUtility.waitForElementToBeVisible(By.id(search_bar_id));
            searchBar.sendKeys(stringToSearch);// search for contact
            appiumUtility.generalWait(3000);
            WebElement searchedElement = appiumUtility.waitForElementToBeVisible(findViewById);
            System.out.println("returning searched element");
            return searchedElement;
        }
```

But there is some delay between element get visible and get clicked.In that delay element which was on 4th position comes to 3rd position due to search operation and wrong element get clicked.Please suggest how to handle such situation.One of my thought was to wait until only single element is visible in list view but need a better approach.

I have tried this line but does not seems working

```
"//android.widget.ListView[0]/android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='ADMIN']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it, I think it will help you

```
protected void waitForVisibilityOf(By locator) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }
```

if the expected element under scroll view, you can use scroll method also

Comment: needed that locator only

Answer (score 0):

I tried this Xpath and it is working fine :

```
//android.widget.ListView//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='ADMIN']
```